# Does Teradata reuse values when an identity column is defined as GENERATED BY DEFAULT... NO CYCLE?

Tags: teradata

I need to delete rows from a Teradata Table that has an IDENTITY column defined as:

```
Some_Id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
           (START WITH 1 
            INCREMENT BY 1 
            MINVALUE 0 
            MAXVALUE 1000000000 
            NO CYCLE)
```

I want to know if Teradata will use again for new rows the values that the rows deleted had. I understood from the Teradata documentation that the `NO CYCLE` won't allow this, but I'm not really sure from what I've read in other posts and how it affects the `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` option.

I know that since it is defined as `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` someone could insert a row with one of the old numbers. I'm asking just for the values automatically generated by Teradata when the column value is not provided.

Comment: NO CYCLE means you'll get an error message when you reach MAXVALUE. No DBMS will reuse identity values of delete rows (unless you reset it, which can't be done in Teradata)

Comment: Isn't that the opposite of what you answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409717/why-does-teradata-identity-column-have-negative-values ???
And if the max value is reached and it's defined as `CYCLE` the identity column would use the deleted values?

Comment: No, *if it's `GENERATED ALWAYS` **without `NO CYCLE`** and the `MAXVALUE` has been reached it will start again at the `MINVALUE`*.